# What mistake I am doing while adding two numbers using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dom-events

I tried adding two numbers by getting the values from the text box and calculate then display it using innerhtml but it isn't working. What mistake am I doing in this code?

```html
<body onload="alert('Hey check out my Calculator')">
 <h1 align="center" >  functional calulator </h1>
 <div class="Calculator" align="center">
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="a1">Enter 1st Number <br><br>
    <input type="text" name="text2" id="a2">Enter 2nd Number<br><br>
    <button   onclick="add()" >Add</button>
    <p id="p1"></p>
    
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
        function add(){
            var a = document.getElementById("a1").value;
            var b = document.getElementByID("a2").value;
            var total = a + b;
            document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = total;
            
            

        }
        </script>
```

Comment: Elaborate on what " it isn't working" means please. What are you getting?

Answer (score 2):

you are adding them as a strings so they are being concatenated you should parse them to integers first

```
var a = parseInt(document.getElementById("a1").value);
var b = parseInt(document.getElementById("a2").value);
var total = a + b;
document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = total;
```

Comment: I suggest to add 10 as second argument of parseInt, old broswers can parse "010" as octal

Answer (score 1):

a, b are strings. Maybe you want to parse them to ints?

Answer (score 0):

`getElementByID` should be `getElementById` in `var b = document.getElementById("a2").value;`

and do `parseInt()` for your a and b to consider them as a number.

```html
<body onload="alert('Hey check out my Calculator')">
  <h1 align="center">  functional calulator </h1>
  <div class="Calculator" align="center">
    <input type="text" name="text1" id="a1">Enter 1st Number
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="text2" id="a2">Enter 2nd Number
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="add()">Add</button>
    <p id="p1"></p>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function add() {
        var a = document.getElementById("a1").value;
        var b = document.getElementById("a2").value;
        var total = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
        document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = total;
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This - You have made spell mistake - Its document.getElementById not document.getElementByID

```html
<body onload="alert('Hey check out my Calculator')">
 <h1 align="center" >  functional calulator </h1>
 <div class="Calculator" align="center">
  <input type="text" name="text1" id="a1">Enter 1st Number <br><br>
  <input type="text" name="text2" id="a2">Enter 2nd Number<br><br>
  <button   onclick="add()" >Add</button>
  <p id="p1"></p>
  
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
  function add(){
           var a = document.getElementById("a1").value;
   var b = document.getElementById("a2").value;
            
   var total = parseInt(a) + parseInt(b);
   document.getElementById("p1").innerHTML = total;
   
   

  }
  </script>
```